# Send string via TCP on receiving commands

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, reader

I'm working on a reader program. It is based on Winorms.

I need a code where winform would send via TCP (port 3573) some data on demand. (by demand I mean command GET when program receives it via TCP.

I'm kind of a newbie so this topic looks pretty hard for me to combine all of these: threads, TCPRead TCP Send, Event Handler...

So I need here help with an entire code or examples how to implement it.

I've tried some example codes from internet but none works (threading, TCPreader and TCPsender, event handling by TCPreaded)

On TCP Reader we receive GET and then we send some string lets say "hello world" by TCP Sender

Comment: this is a large area... frankly, I think it may be ambitious to try and get all that in a SO example - it is a **lot** of work to do networking code properly, and anything that fits in a moderate amount of code is almost certainly *dangerously* naive...

Comment: Yeah, keep reading, researching, practice and it will come. Surely there are examples on the Internet. Good luck

Comment: I got your point, but this is the basic functionality in industrial programming for communications devices with PC and PC with PC on TCP level and then to proceed with hardware data processing with other systems. A clear simple example on this would be useful for a lot of industrial programmers.

Comment: @Ihor.Z. "clear+simple, short, accurate" - pick any two. Last time I blogged about networking code, it took 4 *very* long articles **and** an entire github repo...

Comment: @marc-gravell Okay. :) How about clear and short to start and then troubleshooting problems while they occure?

Comment: @marc-gravell Lets deconstruct the task. First we need to create an event handler when we receive GET on TCP reader, could you help with this?

Comment: receiving data on TCP is almost never an "event" - it is the end of `Receive`, `ReceiveAsync`, or `[Begin|End]Receive`... but if by "event handler" you mean "respond to receiving data"... sure?

Comment: @marc-gravell you right "respond to receiving data" sounds pretty correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are really hard to get right, and the API is just... nasty. Since that is just asking for mistakes, I'm going to recommend using the "pipelines" API, which is far more aligned to modern `async` code *and* is easier to get right (and has far better options in terms of frame processing). So; here's a *pipelines* example;

note that this requires Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial, which is on nuget via:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial" Version="2.0.22" />
```

(adding this will automatically add all the other pieces you need)

```cs
using Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial;
using System;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 9042);
        Console.WriteLine("[server] Starting server...");
        using (var server = new MyServer())
        {
            server.Listen(endpoint);

            Console.WriteLine("[server] Starting client...");
            Task reader;
            using (var client = await SocketConnection.ConnectAsync(endpoint))
            {
                reader = Task.Run(() => ShowIncomingDataAsync(client.Input));

                await WriteAsync(client.Output, "hello");
                await WriteAsync(client.Output, "world");

                Console.WriteLine("press [return]");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            await reader;
            server.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static async Task ShowIncomingDataAsync(PipeReader input)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var read = await input.ReadAsync();
                var buffer = read.Buffer;
                if (buffer.IsEmpty && read.IsCompleted) break; // EOF

                Console.WriteLine($"[client] Received {buffer.Length} bytes; marking consumed");
                foreach (var segment in buffer)
                {   // usually only one segment, but can be more complex
                    Console.WriteLine("[client] " + Program.GetAsciiString(segment.Span));
                }
                input.AdvanceTo(buffer.End); // "we ate it all"
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private static async Task WriteAsync(PipeWriter output, string payload)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
        await output.WriteAsync(bytes);
    }

    internal static unsafe string GetAsciiString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> span)
    {
        fixed (byte* b = span)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, span.Length);
        }
    }
}

class MyServer : SocketServer
{
    protected override Task OnClientConnectedAsync(in ClientConnection client)
        => RunClient(client);
    private async Task RunClient(ClientConnection client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[server] new client: {client.RemoteEndPoint}");
        await ProcessRequests(client.Transport);
        Console.WriteLine($"[server] ended client: {client.RemoteEndPoint}");
    }

    private async Task ProcessRequests(IDuplexPipe transport)
    {
        try
        {
            var input = transport.Input;
            var output = transport.Output;
            while (true)
            {
                var read = await input.ReadAsync();
                var buffer = read.Buffer;
                if (buffer.IsEmpty && read.IsCompleted) break; // EOF

                Console.WriteLine($"[server] Received {buffer.Length} bytes; returning it, and marking consumed");
                foreach (var segment in buffer)
                {   // usually only one segment, but can be more complex
                    Console.WriteLine("[server] " + Program.GetAsciiString(segment.Span));
                    await output.WriteAsync(segment);
                }
                input.AdvanceTo(buffer.End); // "we ate it all"
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

I **could** write this with raw sockets, but it would take a lot more code to show best practice and avoid problems - all of that ugliness is already hidden inside "pipelines".

Output:

```
[server] Starting server...
[server] Starting client...
[server] new client: 127.0.0.1:63076
press [return]
[server] Received 5 bytes; returning it, and marking consumed
[server] hello
[server] Received 5 bytes; returning it, and marking consumed
[client] Received 5 bytes; marking consumed
[client] hello
[server] world
[client] Received 5 bytes; marking consumed
[client] world
```

Comment: Can you use this for arbitrary TCP connections, or is it actually another protocol running on top of TCP and defining message boundaries (Nice, but totally incompatible with existing protocols)?

Comment: @BenVoigt completely raw TCP; normally you'd write a protocol processor to sit on top of pipelines, dealing with the frames etc. The best thing about pipelines is you can say "I checked all the bytes, but only consumed 12 of them" - ideal for backlog processing of incomplete frames, etc

Comment: @BenVoigt example: scan for a CR/LF: if you find one, process everything before it as a frame; if no CR/LF, just say "I read it all,didn't consume anything" - it'll give it you all back next time it has data

Comment: Thanks! This pretty looks likea solution of my problem.
Can you provide information about Net.Framevork versions for each Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial version? Industrial computers are pretty old and sometimes use Windows Embeded or outdated versions in case of internet missing. So there is often no ability to use latest Net.Framework version.

Comment: @Ihor.Z. dammit, in that case it may struggle, but here's the tree: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/ - short version is ".NET Framework 4.6.1, .NET Standard 2.0, or .NET Core App 2.1" - .NET Standard 2.0 is the most "wide" - but : it sounds like you might need raw sockets, which ... is going to be about 8 times as much code!

Comment: @Ihor.Z. if you're limited to very old APIs, you might find a book called "TCP/IP Sockets in C#: Practical Guide for Programmers (The Practical Guides)" useful - it is what I used when I started getting into serious socket work many many years ago - amazon link: https://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Sockets-Practical-Programmers/dp/0124660517/

Comment: @MarcGravell: Ok well frame synchronization always was the complex part.  Having the buffering taken care of for you is nice, but that was always something that was trivially solved by a library-provided buffering class; there doesn't seem to be much advantage to having it deeply integrated into the I/O itself.  Ever since awaitable I/O got added to the framework sockets classes, using them has looked very much like this.

Comment: @BenVoigt except this deals with buffer lifetimes, roll-around, etc, all for you too; lots of stuff that is hard to do so a lot of folks don't bother: now comes for free

Comment: `foreach (var segment in buffer)` makes it pretty clear that I still have to deal with messages split into multiple pieces, and reassemble them myself.  That's exactly the same story as the sockets API itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt in reality, almost all the time it will be a single buffer, and you can always lease a linear buffer and copy it into there if it *isn't* (and you prefer linear)